# Visual Studio errors in .cshtml for new Blazor project that compiles fine? how to disable it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, visual-studio-2019

I just created new blazor project via

> dotnet new blazorhosted

and opened `FetchData.cshtml`, but VS threw 9 errors at me.

Of course whole project is compiling & works fine, but it's very annoying

How can I disable showing errors for `.cshtml` files?

Visual Studio 2019 Preview

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'forecasts' does not exist in the current context  Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    27  Active

Error   CS0115  'Template.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    1   Active

Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Template.__o' and 'Template.__o' Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    1   Active

Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Template.__o' and 'Template.__o' Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    1   Active

Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Template.__o' and 'Template.__o' Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    1   Active

Error   CS0103  The name 'page' does not exist in the current context   Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    4   Active

Error   CS0103  The name 'inject' does not exist in the current context Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    5   Active

Error   CS0103  The name 'forecasts' does not exist in the current context  Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    11  Active

Error   CS0103  The name 'functions' does not exist in the current context  Blazor.Client   FetchData.cshtml    37  Active
```

Comment: This may be related to some defects in the configuration files... Try to create this program in previous version of VS, and compare the results...

Comment: Do you have the *ASP.NET Core Blazor Language Services* extension installed?

Comment: @Codo do you mean if we have that installed for working with VS, we get those errors?

Comment: Question was asked about preview version of Visual Studio 2019 and about Preview version of Blazor which was actively developed at that time. Current question lack of clarity, and unlickely cannot be helpful for new developers, or old one.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Blazor blows up on me and throws errors on lines that have no errors, just like this.

I close the file(s), clean the entire solution, restart my computer, then rebuild just the project I am working on and it goes away.

Maybe that will work for you too.